# TLS handshake random bytes reused

Tags: tls, random, handshake

What would happen if the random bytes provided by the client and the server in the first two messages would be reused by one peer/by both peers?

I think it would highly reduce the provided security, like for example if you use a nonce multiple times, but i am not quite sure.

Does using the same random bytes multiple times lead to a less secure TLS connection. If so, why and what would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server uses the same server_random in the 'server hello' message, then this could enable an attacker to launch a replay attack.  See [SSL replay attack when client/server random is missing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3664/ssl-replay-attack-when-client-server-random-is-missing) for more info.